# remove_if: Predicate error when passing a function returning bool

Tags: c++

I have this pre-defined function.

```
void attack(std::vector<GameObject*> objects, unsigned damage) {


    for (GameObject* object : objects) {
        object->takeDamage(damage);
        auto isDead = object->isDead();
        objects.erase(std::remove_if(objects.begin(),objects.end(),isDead), objects.end());
    }
}
```

This is my isDead function

```
bool isDead() const { 
    if (destructed) { 
            std::cout << "memory error" << std::endl; 
        } 

    return life <= 0; 
}
```

This is the error I keep getting. Have tried a lot of things, but not at all able to figure this one out. Any help appreciated!

**error: expression cannot be used as a function
  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }**

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: You cannot use method like general function you need to use `std::bind`

Comment: Which line is that error happening on?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Note: we **don't** need to see your whole code.

Comment: @Slava While that is true, OP is passing a bool not the actual method. (`auto isDead = object->isDead();`)

Comment: @Borgleader I see missed that

Comment: `if (destructed) { 
            std::cout << "memory error" << std::endl; 
        } ` wat?

Comment: Is removing pointers from this vector a good idea in this case? If objects are allocated with `new`, it's OVER.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `isDead` is a variable in the function. You can't use it as an argument to `remove_if`.
2. You can't use a regular member function as argument to `std::remove_if` either. Use a lambda function instead.
3. Don't erase objects from a container while you are iterating over it using a range for loop.
4. Change the argument to `attack` to be a reference. Otherwise, you will be removing objects from a copy, not the original container.

Here's an updated version of `attack`:

```
void attack(std::vector<GameObject*>& objects, unsigned damage)
{
   for (GameObject* object : objects)
   {
      object->takeDamage(damage);
   }

   objects.erase(std::remove_if(objects.begin(),objects.end(), [](GameObject* object){return object->isDead();}), objects.end());
}
```

Comment: You forgot to apply the damage!

Comment: @Borgleader, noticed that right after I posted the code.

Comment: There is another problem, removing objects from a copy

Comment: Thank you. This was indeed the problem. I was trying to pass a variable!

Answer (score 0):

`isDead()` is a member function of one of your classes, which is exactly why it doesn't work: you did not supply `this` pointer (object instance) for it to be called on. Oh, and the predicate for `remove_if` must have exactly one argument of the type `objects::value_type`.

Do this instead:

```
objects.erase(std::remove_if(objects.begin(),objects.end(),[](GameObject* object){return object->isDead()), objects.end());
```

Comment: Also, as is currently written this loop is O(N^2) since the remove if is inside the loop (it should be at the end)

Comment: @Borgleader: what's worse, it will cause segfault. I didn't notice at first.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I couldn't figure out the way to create the predicate function. Very new to C++.